# Include a file from one directory to another in the same level not working

Tags: php, include

Okay, so I am trying to include a header.php which is in my `WEBROOT/common/header.php`

but if I try to include it on a file in `WEBROOT/legal/legal.php` it does not work.

I have tried the following

```
include 'common/header.php';
include '/common/header.php';
include './common/header.php';
include '../common/header.php';
include __DIR__ . 'common/header.php';
include 'http://siteurl.com/common/header.php';
```

The file structure seems basic enough

```
index.php
-/common/header.php
-/legal/legal.php
```

Comment: Any error messages? Use `require` istead of include to provoke error messages. Which value has __DIR__?

Comment: generally I would suggest that you make use of the functions in php designed to help in these situations - most notably `set_include_path()` ~ once you have established the include path at the top of your scripts in this manner you simply use `include 'file.php'` etc

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'common/header.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') in /home/USER/public_html/MYSITE/legal/legal.php on line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a config file with `.php` or `.ini` that can store `DocumentRoot`.

---

### `.php` approach:

```php
if (!defined('_BASE_DIR_')) {
    define('_BASE_DIR_', '/var/www/html/site');
}
```

Then use this constant in your code like so:

```php
require_once 'constants.php';
require_once _BASE_DIR_.'/legal/legal.php';
```

---

### `.ini` approach:

```
[common]
base_dir=/var/www/html/site
```

Read the **`.ini`** file like so:

```php
$ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);
```

Then include the files like so:

```php
require_once $ini['common']['base_dir'].'/legal/legal.php';
```

---

A word of caution, the require or `parse_ini_file` that reads the constants may have the same path issues you are already encountering. The best solution is to use a single file to load all the pages, but that discussion would be outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks @user2182349 ! Thanks for all the answers. This one worked for me. I made the php call `if (!defined('_BASE_DIR_'))` in my header. Turns out the `../legal/legal.php` was fine on the header but returning a dbconnect error on another file which was halting all. I went with @maxhb 's suggestion of using require so I could get logs, and I noticed my problem. Now I have a form of simple globalization. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Not my header, I meant my global.php file

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use the `__DIR__` constant in combination with `require`, as pointed out earlier. Note that in your example you're missing a directory separator, though:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../common/header.php';
```

For reference, see

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php.